# How can I make pretty dataframe using json file in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, api

I've try to save the data that I received from Open API.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas import DataFrame

def Bring_API():
    url = "api_url/authenticate key/options"
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()
    print(data)
Bring_API()
```

When I receive the API information from the server,
it shows me the JSON file,
but it's very dizzy.  Like below.

```
{"COOKRCP01":{"total_count":"1318","row":[{"RCP_PARTS_DTLS":"sweet potato soup\nsweet potato 100g, sugar 2g, rice powder 3g,water 200ml", "RCP_WAY2":"boil","MANUAL_IMG20":"","MANUAL20":"","RCP_SEQ":"17","INFO_NA":"68","INFO_WGT":"","INFO_PRO":"3","MANUAL_IMG13":"","MANUAL_IMG14":"","MANUAL_IMG15":"","MANUAL_IMG16":"","MANUAL_IMG10":"","MANUAL_IMG11":"","MANUAL_IMG12":"","MANUAL_IMG17":"","MANUAL_IMG18":"","MANUAL_IMG19":"","INFO_FAT":"6","HASH_TAG":"","MANUAL_IMG02":"http://www.foodsafetykorea.go.kr/uploadimg/cook/20_00017_2.png","MANUAL_IMG03":"http://www.foodsafetykorea.go.kr/uploadimg/cook/20_00017_3.png","RCP_PAT2":"dessert","MANUAL_IMG04":"","MANUAL_IMG05":"","MANUAL_IMG01":"http://www.foodsafetykorea.go.kr/uploadimg/cook/20_00017_1.png","MANUAL01":"1. wash and cut.","ATT_FILE_NO_MK":"http://www.foodsafetykorea.go.kr/uploadimg/cook/10_00017_1.png","MANUAL_IMG06":"","MANUAL_IMG07":"","MANUAL_IMG08":"","MANUAL_IMG09":"","MANUAL08":"","MANUAL09":"","MANUAL06":"","MANUAL07":"","MANUAL04":"4. mix.","MANUAL05":"","MANUAL02":"2. boil it.","MANUAL03":"3. make","ATT_FILE_NO_MAIN":"http://www.foodsafetykorea.go.kr/uploadimg/cook/10_00017_2.png","MANUAL11":"","MANUAL12":"","MANUAL10":"","INFO_CAR":"35","MANUAL19":"","INFO_ENG":"205","MANUAL17":"","MANUAL18":"","RCP_NM":"sweet potato soup","MANUAL15":"","MANUAL16":"","MANUAL13":"","MANUAL14":""}],"RESULT":{"MSG":"sucess.","CODE":"INFO-000"}}}
```

So I try to make it clear, using the pandas dataframe module.

```
df = pd.read_json (r'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\1.json')
print (df)
```

However when I doing it, It was very different from what I thought.

```
                                                 COOKRCP01
RESULT               {'MSG': 'Success.', 'CODE': 'INFO-000'}
row          [{'RCP_PARTS_DTLS': 'Sweet Potato
Sweet Potato 100g, Sugar 2...
total_count                                               1318
```

Why can't I make the result like other pretty dataframe. ex)

```
  0  'RCP_PARTS_DTLS'                    'RCP_NM' 
  1  Sweet potato,sugar,rice powder      SWeet Potato Soup
```

Can someone teach me how to eliminate the key and value in json file (or sort specific key and value from json file) what module should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can load it as a JSON file. Using json module, json.load()

and then passing to pandas dataframe only what you want as a table:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data["COOKRCP01"]["row"])
```

> LS RCP_WAY2  ... MANUAL13 MANUAL14
> 0  sweet potato soup\nsweet potato 100g, sugar 2g...     boil  ...

[1 rows x 54 columns]

You can Transpose it to get:

```
print (df.T)
```

> RCP_PARTS_DTLS    sweet potato soup\nsweet potato 100g, sugar 2g...
> RCP_WAY2                                                       boil
> MANUAL_IMG20
> MANUAL20